# sending erlang records to a c program

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, erlang

I am working on my assignment and part of it is sending erlang terms to a c program that will be able to communicate with each other through a established tcp connection.

I was able to send numbers, lists, boolean, binaries and able to decode them in my c program to get the sent message. I am using the ei module to do this stuff. On the erlang side, I am encoding using etf like term_to_binary/1 and others.

That said, I am wondering how can I send records over that socket encoded on the erlang side and decoding on the c -side. ei has many functions to get primitives data types decoded from a binary format but not to get composite one like records.

Records are simple like `-rd(person, {name = "", email = ""})` 
I can send it as

```
gen_tcp:send(Socket, term_to_binary(#person{name="stack", age = 16})).
```

How do I decode on the c-side.

I have googled but not a lot of resources on this. Please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Erlang [External Term Format](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/erl_ext_dist.html) is in detail described in the [documentation](http://erlang.org/erldoc). There is [Erlang Interface](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/erl_interface/index.html) library application which contain [`ei`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ei.html) library with detailed [Encoding, Decoding and Sending Erlang Terms](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/erl_interface/ei_users_guide.html#id60655) documentation. Note there is more low-level interface `ei` working directly with buffers encoded in Erlang External Term Format and `erl_interface` working with `ETERM`s which are equivalent to the Erlang terms internally used in BEAM VM.

There is also a whole chapter devoted to the topic in the book [Erlang and OTP in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/erlang-and-otp-in-action) which shows a practical example using `ei` but just scratches the surface. Official documentation is far more detailed and complete. Official documentation contains [Interoperability Tutorial User's Guide](http://erlang.org/doc/tutorial/users_guide.html) with complete examples of working code with [Erl_Interface](http://erlang.org/doc/tutorial/erl_interface.html) although doesn't contain complete examples of using low-level `ei`.